# How to know the form is submitted on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I have a form and I want to set focus on the status message when the form is submitted.

I have tried the following code.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
  $('.messages--status').focus();
});
```

But the problem is that when I submit the form the page reloads and therefore my code is not working.

Is there any way to find on page reload that the form is submitted?

So that can I set the focus on the status message based on that condition?

Comment: Do you submit your form with `GET` or `POST` method ?

Comment: I'm submitting the form with POST

Comment: What langage do you use server side ?

Comment: I'm using php. basically a cms Drupal.

Comment: You can set a php var to `true` when you've receive your data and in the script `echo` a js `function` with php if  `$var  = true`

Answer (score 0):

Append a query parameter your url, and show the message based on that.

Eg. suppose your form action url is `www.foo.com/form/submit` then make it, `www.foo.com/form/submit?submitted`,

so when the page loads you can check whether submitted is there in the URL or not.